# Java 8: Recursive stream map

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, java-stream

In my `Library` class there is a `Set<Library> items` field. Hence there in the `LibraryDTO` I have `Set<LibraryDTO> items`. When I build a `Library` from the `LibraryDTO`, I realized that I will enter an infinite loop in converting the DTO to an entity in this items field, example:

```
private Library buildLibraryFromLibraryDTO(LibraryDTO libraryDTO) {

return Library.builder()        
        .items(libraryDTO.getItems().stream().map(library -> Library.builder()                      
                .items(library.getItems().stream().map ... repeats the same DTO to entity conversion process from the above level)                  
                .build()).collect(Collectors.toSet()))

        .build();
}
```

I thought about making a recursive method going through the items stream but I'm having difficulties with logic. How could I do it? I researched and saw some examples of recursion with stream but was unable to replicate for my case. Thank you

Comment: How many level do you have data ? like LibraryDTO I have Set<LibraryDTO> items and every LibraryDTO of Set have Set<LibraryDTO> value or null ?

Comment: Is the issue that during execution you enter an infinite loop, or is the issue that you would have to write an infinite amount of code to solve the problem? If the latter is the issue, why not call `buildLibraryFromLibraryDTO` as part of `map` instead of repeating the code?

Comment: @Rono I should run through the items until this list is null so I don't know how many levels I have but I know the condition to stop

Comment: @Marcono1234 Yes, the issue is that I would have to write an infinite amount of code. When you said "call buildLibraryFromLibraryDTO as part of map" is something like: Library.builder().items(buildLibraryFromLibraryDTO(library).getItems()) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a base case when you don't need to call recursively to avoid an infinite loop. Means when `libraryDTO.getItems()` is null then don't call again.

You can use ternary operator to check if `libraryDTO.getItems()` is not null then call `buildLibraryFromLibraryDTO` for every item else null.

```
private Library buildLibraryFromLibraryDTO(LibraryDTO libraryDTO) {
return Library.builder()
        .items(libraryDTO.getItems() != null 
                       ? libraryDTO.getItems()
                         .stream()
                         .map(library -> buildLibraryFromLibraryDTO(library))
                         .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                       : null)
        .build();
}
```